# C# XmlTextWriter deleting tags

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display XML in my ASP.NET MVC application and I'm using the `XmlTextWriter` class to do it. My code:

```
string result = "";

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode);
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

try
{
    // Load the XmlDocument with the XML.
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

    xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    // Write the XML into a formatting XmlTextWriter
    xmlDocument.WriteContentTo(xmlTextWriter);
    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
    memoryStream.Flush();

    // Have to rewind the MemoryStream in order to read its contents.
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    // Read MemoryStream contents into a StreamReader.
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);

    // Extract the text from the StreamReader.
    String formattedXML = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

    result = formattedXML;
}
catch (XmlException e)
{
    //Print
}
```

This outputs XML in the correct indentation, but the issue is that the tags wrapping around the values are gone. For example:
`<test> this </test>`
The `<test> </test>` tags are missing. How can I keep those?

Comment: How are you displaying your XML?

Comment: I've tried your code and can't reproduce the issue.  I'm going to guess you just need to escape the content before putting it on a web page.  As an aside, all this code could be replaced with `XDocument.Parse(xml).ToString()`.

Comment: @CharlesMager What do you mean I need to escape my content?

Comment: Have you put a break point on `result` to see if the value does or doesn't have the tags?  My guess is that the XML is output to your web browser and your browser is just seeing these as invalid html tags and ignoring them, hence you just see the content.